# orignal network proxy settings

Tags: 12.04, networking, proxy

What are the original network proxy settings in Ubuntu 12.04? I changed my network proxy settings but now I can't download any software from Ubuntu Software Centre. An error occurs "failed to downlaod package files,check your internet settings".

Can anyone help me with this problem? What should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu assumes it doesn't need to use a proxy unless you tell it that it needs to.  The Software Centre is a front end to `apt-get` so you will need to configure this to use a proxy.  If I had time I'd post a full answer but details on how to configure are here: [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Answer (score 0):

The default is "no proxy".  Do you have a proxy server?  Where exactly all did you change the proxy settings?

If not, clear the Proxy in Gnome (or wherever you changed it), eg set it to None.  To locate the proxy settings, you can enter the word "Proxy" in the Desktop search tool.

Note: If you specified a proxy during installation, then that will become the default in some places, specifically the package manager and the desktop environment.